# Unable to locate factory with name [default] [Modules\Brokerquotes\Entities\Insuree]

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, artisan-migrate

I definitely have a factory

```
$factory->define(Modules\Brokerquotes\Entities\Insuree::class,....
```

And in a DatabaseSeeder I have

```
factory("Modules\\Brokerquotes\\Entities\\Insuree", 5)->create()-> ......
```

But when I try to call the seeder class directly using `php artisan db:seed --class=....` I get the subject error

> Unable to locate factory with name [default] [Modules\Brokerquotes\Entities\Insuree].

I have tried to `composer dumpautoload` but still doesn't work

I just need to run some individual seeders from time to time.

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the namespace I assume you're using [Asgard CMS](https://asgardcms.com/) and that you've put your Insuree Model Factory in your Module's factories directory. This won't work because by default the lookup for Model Factories is fixed to `database_path('factories')`, see the following in the Factory class:

```
/**
 * Create a new factory container.
 *
 * @param  \Faker\Generator  $faker
 * @param  string|null  $pathToFactories
 * @return static
 */
public static function construct(Faker $faker, $pathToFactories = null)
{
    $pathToFactories = $pathToFactories ?: database_path('factories');

    return (new static($faker))->load($pathToFactories);
}
```

Move your Module Factory to your project's factories directory:

```
<PROJECT>/
├── database/
│   └── factories/
│       └── InsureeFactory.php
└── Modules/
```

& then re-run your seeder:

```
namespace Modules\Brokerquotes\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BrokerquotesDatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        factory(\Modules\Brokerquotes\Entities\Insuree::class, 5)->create();
    }
}
```

Artisan command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=Modules\\Brokerquotes\\Database\\Seeders\\BrokerquotesDatabaseSeeder
```

Answer (score 2):

I tackled with the same problem, and the more 'standard' solution would be to:

Add `registerFactories` function in your [ModuleName]ServiceProvider.php like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerFactories();
    ...
    ...
}
```

And define it:

```
public function registerFactories()
{
    if (! app()->environment('production')) {
        app(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::class)->load(__DIR__ . '/../Database/Factories');
    }
}
```